# Error: "Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set" when it is set

Tags: html, .net, header, content-security-policy

I am having an issue with the following error:

`Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400|500|600|700' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

This is a .net web project, and I am trying to load some styles in my layout.

Here is the head of my layout.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src data: 'self' fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com; style-src-elem data: 'self' fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com;" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/templates/dist/css/style.css" />
</head>
```

and my in my style.css I call this:

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400|500|600|700);`

I don't know why it is saying 'Note that `style-src-elem' was not explicitly set` when it is clearly added in my meta header. I might be formatting it wrong but I have tried several different configurations for the CSP and no luck.

Comment: Maybe a bit 'Brute Force', but does it work without the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">`?

Comment: @RenevanderLende, I actually found the issue. I am using a .Net Core app and the controller is using `[SecurityHeaders]` so the ones I am adding are being overwritten.