# Error: “Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set” when it is set

Tags: electron, content-security-policy, google-font-api

[Having the same problem as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066253/error-note-that-style-src-elem-was-not-explicitly-set-when-it-is-set) but am not using .NET so I don't know what the answer to this problem is. I am using Electron.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src-elem 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
```

Here is the error:

`Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

The question is here, `'style-src-elem'` IS explicitly set. I have no idea what is going on. Please help

Answer (score 7):

Nevermind, figured it out! I thought I could separate the `<meta>` tags for readability, but it turns out that was not the case. Each `<meta>` tag was over-writing the previous, leaving everything to check for the last `content="default-src 'self'"` `<meta>` tag. Here is the working code for anyone that is having a similar problem:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self';
        style-src-elem 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
        font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com;
    ">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">



    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Yeap, several meta's means several CSPs, those works a tricky way. But you still have an error `Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com...` have a look in Firefox or Safari. You have to duplicate content from `style-src-elem` into `style-src`, because some browsers do [not support `style-src-elem`](https://csplite.com/csp/test235/#results) directive.

Comment: @granty Possibly would need to do that on the web for different browsers. In my case, I am developing an electron program. Electron is run exclusively on Chromium, so there shouldn't be an issue with multiple browsers.